# Unknown column in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

Tags: mysql

Why am I getting this error? Error is showing up in the `OR` clause, but I'm selecting `gl_ID` inside the `SELECT` statement.

```
; DECLARE v_firstDate DATETIME
SET @p_ID = 368
SELECT SUBDATE(NOW(), 1) INTO v_firstDate;
SELECT t_ID, t_firstName, t_lastName
FROM t_table
WHERE
((@p_ID IN (
        SELECT tt_ID
        FROM tt_tableTwo
        INNER JOIN st_stats ON (st_ID = tt_ID)
        INNER JOIN da_data ON (da_ID = st_ID AND da_name IN ("allCompanies", "allglobals"))
    )
))
OR
(
    (gl_ID IN ( //problem is here
        SELECT gl_ID
        FROM gl_globals
        INNER JOIN tr_transport ON (tr_id = gl_caseID AND tr_idOther = @p_ID)
        INNER JOIN co_countries ON (co_ID = gl_ID AND co_ID = @p_ID)
        )
    )
)
```

*Error message:*

> Unknown column 'gl_ID' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

Should I be using an `AS` or a `HAVING`?

Comment: Is your gl_ID exists in t_table ?

Comment: @LoïcDiBenedetto No, it exists in gl_globals

Comment: Try using tablename.gl_ID format in both the outer ant the inner query, so that mysql knows exactly which gl_ID field you are referring to.

Comment: There's too many brackets in the query.

Comment: @Shadow Doesn't help - the error changes to `Unknown column 'gl_globals.gl_ID' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'`

Comment: @P.Salmon I don't think the brackets make a difference, unless they're unpaired

Comment: I don't understand your statement though, you compare an unknown field with a result of a subquery, your first gl_ID field doesn't exist in the scope of t_table

Comment: @Still_learning please add your table definitions

Comment: @LoïcDiBenedetto Thanks, fixed it, I was missing the inner join for `gl_globals` at the top of the query

Comment: @Still_learning ;)

Comment: Reason for downvote??? What isn't valid about the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gl_ID` is not accessible in the `OR` clause because it doesn't exist in `t_table`. An inner join under the first `FROM` clause solves the problem.

```
; DECLARE v_firstDate DATETIME
SET @p_ID = 368
SELECT SUBDATE(NOW(), 1) INTO v_firstDate;
SELECT t_ID, t_firstName, t_lastName
FROM t_table
INNER JOIN gl_globals ON (t_ID = gl_ID) // fix
WHERE
((@p_ID IN (
        SELECT tt_ID
        FROM tt_tableTwo
        INNER JOIN st_stats ON (st_ID = tt_ID)
        INNER JOIN da_data ON (da_ID = st_ID AND da_name IN ("allCompanies", "allglobals"))
    )
))
OR
(
    (gl_ID IN (
        SELECT gl_ID
        FROM gl_globals
        INNER JOIN tr_transport ON (tr_id = gl_caseID AND tr_idOther = @p_ID)
        INNER JOIN co_countries ON (co_ID = gl_ID AND co_ID = @p_ID)
        )
    )
)
```